# Filtering dataframe with tuples

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, tuples

I've got a dataframe that looks like this that has longitude as a first element of a tuple, and latitude as a second element:
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/41zpN.jpg
How can I filter dataframe to select only rows where longitude would be in range (19.07,19.82) and latitude in range (-17.09,-20.37).
Thanks!

Comment: if you want to get help here please have a quick look in [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). What have you tried so far? provide a [minimal reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: You want to do this for all columns? And can you plz provide your expected output

Comment: `df.explode` might be a place to start looking. but the many columns there seem a bit overwhelming...

Comment: Could you provide a sample of the data in a code-based format? [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) is worth a read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you didn't state which column you want to filter, here is my solution to get `(longitude, latitude)` pairs in those ranges only for column `1`:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'0': [(133.79, -72.91812133789062), (133.50, -72.95),
                        (133.22, -72.98)], '1': [(133.56, -72.97),
                        (133.28, -73.006), (19.59, -18.04)]})
lat_lower, lat_upper = 19.07, 19.82
long_lower, long_upper = -20.37, -17.09
col = df['1']
filtered = df.loc[(lat_lower < col.str[0]) & (col.str[0] < lat_upper) & (long_lower < col.str[1]) & (col.str[1] < long_upper)]
print(filtered)
```

output is:

```
0                     1
(133.22, -72.98)  (19.59, -18.04)
```

Here as you can see, column `1` has only values in the range you requested, but column `0` does not.
If you want rows with all its columns in those ranges, then you should repeat the same for all other columns.